# Detect and ignore touches on iAd banners

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, iad

I have a Sprite Kit game that first displays a menu screen. The game starts when you tap anywhere on the screen. I am displaying iAd's. The problem I have is when a user taps the iAd banner to view the add, GameScene is responding to the tap and starting the game. Ideally I want to detect that the touch was on the iAd banner and not start the game in this case.

GameScene.m

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    // I dont want to start game if the touch was on the iAd Banner
    NSLog(@"Touch detected - Start the game....");

    [self startGame];
}
```

Comment: what's the code that starts the game?

Comment: I omitted that as it didn't think it added anything to the question. Updated post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead. Check if `recognizer.view != adBanner`

Comment: SpriteKit scenes normally uses the touch methods. You can use UITapGestureRecognizer there, but if you add them additionally think about performance

Comment: Thanks. I have set up the UITapGestureRecognizer in the didMoveToView method and replaced touchesDetected with custom handleTap method. As the gesture is only registered on the view, it is not detected when the iAd banner is tapped, so no need to do recognizer.view != adBanner

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the SKView smaller in the GameViewController?

Try making

```
yourScene.size = CGSize(skView.bounds.size.width, skView.bounds.size.height-heightOfiAdBanner)
```

Change `heightOfiAdBanner` with the actual height of the iAd banner. And then position the scene wherever you must to see it properly (depending on where you display the banner). Remember to use

```
yourScene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

when you remove the banner. With this solution you do not have to use any gesture recognizer.

Answer (score -1):

One option is to check the location.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    // get location
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    // check position
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.adBanner.frame, location) {
        // start game

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in this instance, as the location returned is relative to the iAd banner, not the overall view

Comment: You don´t have to use a static position. I added a dynamic version.