# Pause game while user interacts with iAd Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, iad

I don't currently understand the approved solution to the problem linked below:

> use a UITapGestureRecognizer instead. Check if recognizer.view != adBanner

[Detect and ignore touches on iAd banners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246378/detect-and-ignore-touches-on-iad-banners)

I am having the same problem with a Sprite Kit game but in Swift and I am not sure how to implement the approved solution. Can someone provide a code example?

Here is my code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        // If iAd banner has been tapped, do not start the game

        // Else game starts
    }
}

func adStopsGame(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Game stopped")
}
```

Comment: I would be very careful if that is even allowed. The iAd is there for some users to touch on it if they see something interesting - if you disable the ability to touch it that might easily conflict with apple iAd ToS

Comment: I don't want to stop the user using the ad, only stop the game from running in the background whilst they are looking at the ad.

Comment: Ah, okay, that is very reasonable request, you might want to change your question title to better reflect that, something like "pause game while user watches iAd"

Comment: there is an iAD delegate method that you use be using `bannerViewActionShouldBegin:willLeaveApplication:`  In this method, you pause your game,  the touch should not be going from the iAd view down to the game scene though,  if it is,  then you do not have the view setup correctly

Comment: That works thank you

Comment: @MaxGoodridge how do you tell the scene to `pause` from the ViewController, because i am using iAd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `bannerViewActionShouldBegin(_:willLeaveApplication:)`.

> This method is called when the user taps the banner view. Your
>   application controls whether the action is triggered. To allow the
>   action to be triggered, return true. To suppress the action, return
>   false. Your application should almost always allow actions to be
>   triggered; preventing actions may alter the advertisements your
>   application sees and reduce the revenue your application earns through
>   iAd.

For a complete list of `ADBannerView` delegate methods refer to: [ADBannerViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/).